# Print /dev/tcp response without keyboard input

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cat, tcp

I am using the following to send and receive from a TCP socket:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/port
echo -e "textcommand\r" >&3
cat <&3
exec 3<&-;exec 3>&-
```

The cat <&3 line displays the response from the localhost in the terminal, but I have to use Ctrl+d or Ctrl+c to return to the command line. How can I print the response from localhost and return to the command line without any keyboard interaction?

EDIT

```
(echo -en "textcommand\r"; sleep 1) | telnet localhost port
```

The above works as an alternative. Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24204924/5900282

EDIT 2

There was a similar issue here: [Capturing data from a Fluke 1620a via Bash /dev/tcp file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170048/398408)

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeout`:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/port
echo -e "textcommand\r" >&3
timeout 0.2 cat <&3
exec 3<&-; exec 3>&-
```